# How to create an image pattern for a path with Snap.svg?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

Failing to create an image pattern for a path element through [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Element.pattern) library. Is it possible?

Creating a `Paper.image()` and then trying to call `Element.pattern()` on it doesn't seem to be an option or a working solution.

So i wonder whether it's possible to do so using Snap.svg lib. or Should i generate the needed ,  elements myself and then append them to the needed svg 'by hands'?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
var paper = Snap(200,200);
var pattern = paper.image("logo.svg",0,0,50,50)
   .pattern(0,0,50,50);
var path = paper.path("M0,0h200v200h-200z").attr("fill", pattern);
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly. That's what i tried to do at first. 
The thing i missed is 'paper.append(pattern)'
Without doing so – my defs tag was empty in svg and path was filled with black color instead (though a pattern exsisted in dom and was referenced by id in fill attribute of path).
Why do i have to append seems to be an other question.

Comment: See https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/Snap.svg/issues/207 Parhaps it's Snap.svg's bug.

Comment: This saved my day! :D